# efficient replacement for m2=(m1==v) for cv::UMat?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I got the following code (example) to create a mask, which uses cv:Mat:

```
int v;
cv::Mat m1; // being a submat
cv::Mat mask = (m1==v);
```

These lines are derived from the python prototype

```
mask = np.where( m1[x1:x2,y1:y2]==v, 255, 0 );
```

In the c++ version I'd like to use UMat instead of Mat because there's a larger processing pipeline around this one line. Sadly it seems to me that MatExpressions (like the `m1==v` above) are not implemnted for cv::UMat in OpenCV3.4.1. Is that correct?

Are there operations available on cv::UMat with which I could efficiently mimic the `mask=(m1==v)` to obtain the same mask?
My current code (converting from UMat to Mat, i.e. copying from graphics mem to main mem and then doing the cv::Mat operation) is not efficient.

using c++11, gcc5.4.0, opencv3.4.1

NB: The question is not about possibly different values in the mask between python and c++ version.

Comment: Can't you use `threshold` function, like `threshold(m1, mask, v, 255, THRESH_BINARY)`?

Comment: @dhanushka Yes, you are right, I might use two threshold statements: `threshold( m1, mask, v, v, THRESH_TOZERO_INV );` and `threshold( mask, mask, v-1, 255, THRESH_BINARY );` It's not very elegant, but it should do the job and be way faster than copying into main mem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [`cv::compare`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga303cfb72acf8cbb36d884650c09a3a97)?

Comment: @DanMašek , your comment helped me again (reviewed my question + comments because needed the thought again) - do you want to turn it into an answer? Maybe I'd self-answer when you don't want to, to have an answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

As @DanMašek correctly pointed out, `cv::compare` is my friend in this case:

```
// having some UMat m1 and some (let's say) double v
cv::UMat mask;
cv::compare( m1, cv::Scalar{v}, mask, cv::CMP_EQ );
```